# Bypass specific URL from Akamai if certain cookie exist

Tags: cookies, akamai

I would like Akamai not to cache certain URLs if a specified cookie exist (i.e) If user logged in on specific pages. Is there anyway we can do with Akamai?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Edge Server doesn't check for a cookie before it does the request to your origin server and I have never seen anything like that in any of their menus, conf screens or documentation.

However, there are a few ways I can think of that you can get the effect that I think you're looking for.

1. You can specify in the configuration settings for the respective digital property what path(s) or URL(s) you don't want it to cache. If you're talking about a logged on user, you might have a path that only they would get to or you could set up such a thing server side. E.g. for an online course you would have `www.course.com/php.html` that anybody could get to whereas you might use `www.course.com/student/php-lesson-1.html` for the actual logged on lessons content. Specifying that `/student/*` would not be cached would solve that.
2. If you are serving the same pages to both logged on and not-logged on users and can't do it that way, you could check server-side if they're logged on and if so add a cache-breaker to the links so when they follow a link a cache-breaker is automatically added. You could also do this client side if you want, but it would be more secure and faster to do it server-side. As a note on this, this could be userid-random#. That would keep it unique enough when combined with the page that nobody else would request it and get the earlier 'cache-broken' page.
3. If neither of the above are workable, there is one other way I can think of, which is a bit unconventional to say the least, but it would work. Create symbolically linked directory in your document root with another name so that you can apply the first option and exempt it from cacheing. Then you check if the guy is logged on and if so prepend the extra directory to the links. From akamai's point of view `www.mysite.com/logged-on/page.html` can be exempt from cache where `www.mysite.com/content/page.html` is cached. On your server if `/logged-on/` symbolically links over to `/content/` then you're all set.
4. When they login you could send them to a subdomain which is set up as a ServerAlias, so on your side it's the same, but on Akamai has differnt cache handling rules.

Answer (score 3):

The good news, is that I have done exactly this in the past for the Top Gear site (www.topgear.com/uk). The logic goes that if a cookie is present (in this case "TGCACHEKEY") then the Akamai cache is to be bypassed for certain url paths. This basically turns off Akamai caching of html pages when logged in.

The bad news is that you require an Akamai consultant to make this change for you.

If this isn't an option for you, then Peter's suggestions are all good ones. I considered all of these before implementing the cookie based approach for Top Gear, but in the end none were feasible.

Remember also that Akamai strips cookies for cached resources by default. That may or may not effect you in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Following the same answer than @llevera, you can use the cookies on CloudFlare without intervention of engineers to make the change for you.

Having that sort of cookies to bypass content is a technique that its becoming more popular with the time, and even bug companies like Magento are using it for Magento 2 platform.

But solutions from above still valid, Maybe Akamai supports that that already now, we are in 2017!