# Bypass specific URL from Akamai if header exist

Tags: akamai

I would like Akamai not to cache certain URLs if the origin server sends a specific header. Is this possible to do with Akamai?

The question has been covered pretty well here: [Bypass specific URL from Akamai if certain cookie exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540341/bypass-specific-url-from-akamai-if-certain-cookie-exist)

I would be surprised if there is no build in way to do this. In many cases, it is too difficult to configure these rules in Akamai. Only the origin server knows when a page cannot be cached.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible using Akamai Property Manager configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you have any more details? Does it require a specific subscription/license or is this configuration option always available?

Comment: no addition subscription required for this. Its just a configuration change. In Configuration there are two types. 1) Configuration Manager -> This is the older version of configuration with very limited functionality for us to configure and need to go to akamai representative whenever we need advanced changes. 2) Property Manager -> This is the new version of configuration with N number of features that you can configure yourself without any akamai team help. Off-course you can contact them to review if you like but there will not be any cost. In previous case akamai charge for making changes

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Property Manager, you can do this with the Property Manager API or in Luna.

The Property Manager API documentation is here:
[PAPI](https://developer.akamai.com/api/luna/papi/overview.html)